# react - tick logic for material-ui radio button

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a minimalist function whereby I'm providing two choices in the form of radio inputs: "bull" or "bear".

Full code below:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import RadioButton from 'material-ui/RadioButton';

const styles = {
    rootRadio: {
        //left:"37%",
        //position:'absolute'
    }
}

function RadioComp() {

    const [riskP, setRiskP] = useState("bull")

    const handleRisk = (e) => {
        setRiskP(e.target.value)
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h2>Risk profile</h2>
            <div>
                <span>Bull</span>
                <RadioButton
                    style={styles.rootRadio}
                    value='bull'
                    checked={riskP==='bull'}
                    onChange={handleRisk}
                />
            </div>
            <div>
                <span>Bear</span>
                <RadioButton
                    style={styles.rootRadio}
                    value='bear'
                    checked={riskP==='bear'}
                    onChange={handleRisk}
                />
            </div>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}

export default RadioComp;
```

As seen above, I have tried to configure this logic using `useState()`:

```
const [riskP, setRiskP] = useState("bull")

const handleRisk = (e) => {
    setRiskP(e.target.value)
}
```

However, in the view, clicking on "bear" doesn't do anything. It seems to be locked on "bull."

### Question

Comment: Hey this is because you are setting value="bear" either you need to make it dynamic or pass `bear` in `defaultValue`

Answer (score 1):

You have to use RadioGroup with FormControl option.

```
import React from 'react';
import Radio from '@material-ui/core/Radio';
import RadioGroup from '@material-ui/core/RadioGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import FormLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormLabel';

 export default function RadioButtonsGroup() {
   const [value, setValue] = React.useState('female');

   const handleChange = (event) => {
    setValue(event.target.value);
   };

  return (
    <FormControl component="fieldset">
      <FormLabel component="legend">Gender</FormLabel>
        <RadioGroup name="gender1" value={value} onChange={handleChange}>
        <FormControlLabel value="female" control={<Radio />} label="Female" />
        <FormControlLabel value="male" control={<Radio />} label="Male" />
        <FormControlLabel value="other" control={<Radio />} label="Other" />
        </RadioGroup>
    </FormControl>
   );
  }
```